# Design and Analysis of Algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, analysis

Now, to sort some limited number of registers, we often use RAM to hold elements under process. The problem is when we are asked to sort millions of random registers where each register contains set of elements. This huge file cannot be sorted using traditional sorting algorithms . how i can solve this problem.

Comment: Read the book "Design and Analysis of Algorithm"

Answer (score 0):

You need to look  an efficient algorithm for sorting data that is not completely read into memory. A few adaptations to Merge-Sort can achieve this.

Here is the [Java Implementation](https://github.com/lemire/externalsortinginjava) of merge sort that sorts very large files:

Take a look into these too:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting